# Does apache beam for python support flink runner commercially?

Tags: apache-beam

Does apache beam for python support flink runner right now ? or even the portable runner ? And is beam for java supported by flink runner commercially ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both python and java is supported for the Apache Flink runner.

> It is important to understand that the Flink Runner comes in two flavors:
>
> - A legacy Runner which supports only Java (and other JVM-based languages)
> - A portable Runner which supports Java/Python/Go

Ref: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/flink/

Comment: I'm going through the link. Where is this command- ./gradlew :beam-sdks-python-container:docker written ? Inside the apache beam code ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to define what commercially supported means:

Do you want to run the Flink Runner as a service, similarly to what Google Cloud Dataflow provides? If so, the closest to this is [Amazon's Kinesis Data Analytics](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-analytics/), but it is really just a managed Flink cluster.

Many companies use the Flink Runner and contribute back to the Beam project, e.g. Lyft, Yelp, Alibaba, Ververica. This could be seen as a form of commercial support. There are also various consultancies, e.g. [BigDataInstitute](https://www.bigdatainstitute.io), [Ververica](https://ververica.com), which could help you manage your Flink Runner applications.